# Ambiguity at the time of plotting

Tags: python, matplotlib, operating-system

It is easily verified that depending of the version/operating system, the plots done with Python differ meaningly in its appearance/resolution: how to solve that?

Answer (score 1):

I would say, ensure that you're using the same backend, fonts, etc. by having identical .matplotlibrc files, and specify the dpi of your plots in your code.

Answer (score 0):

Beyond different `.matplotlibrc` files, there are two likely reasons for this.

1) Different fonts.

For example, `Arial` is likely to be the default san serif on Windows, but it usually isn't available on Linux.  This is the main reason why you'd see different results.  The resolution shouldn't change, however.

2) The interactive backend is likely to be different on different OS-es.

The displayed window (but not the saved .png, .pdf, etc) will appear very different depending on the interactive backend used. Which backends are available will depend on how matplotlib was built.  `TkAgg` is a very common backend, but Tkinter isn't available by default on OSX (or rather, the version of Tkinter shipped with most OSX versions isn't compatible).  Therefore, it's common to see the `OSX` interactive backend on OSX.

Again, the second one mostly just affects the style of the interactive window that pops up when you call `show`.  The contents of the window will be essentially identical.

What exact differences are you seeing?